# Why ¹H–¹⁴N coupling is not observed in ¹H NMR

Tags: spectroscopy, nmr-spectroscopy, spin

Since the nuclear spin value of $\ce{^{14}N}$ is $I = 1$, we should expect a coupling between $\ce{^1H}$ and $\ce{^{14}N}$. Hence, the proton peak in a primary amine $(\ce{-NH2})$ should split in a triplet ($2 × 1 × 1 + 1 = 3$).

But generally that is not observed. Is this because of lower gyromagnetic ratio of $\ce{^{14}N}$ that leads to very less population difference between ground and excited state, or is there some other reason behind it?

Comment: Although not exactly the same question, [my answer here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/81516/symmetry-and-nmr-linewidths-of-quadrupolar-nuclei/81552#81552) addresses this issue, in particular the last paragraph, although one would likely need to read the whole thing.

Comment: The highly symmetric ammonium cation does in fact display ¹H-¹⁴N coupling, forming a nice sharp 1:1:1 triplet in the ¹H-NMR spectrum, as shown [here](http://chem.ch.huji.ac.il/nmr/techniques/1d/row2/n.html#n14). Once the source of much confusion, before an amazing *a-ha* moment!